# Usage of indefinite articles in a sentence

Tags: articles

Should we use articles highlighted in bold in the sentence below?

> A video, that not only engages but also impresses target audience with a unique story, worldwide achievements, touching revelation, and in the end, **a** new hope for **a** better future.

Comment: First article is not necessary (or the word 'new' - unless it's just a preference?), second one is necessary.

Comment: You need also need an `its` between impresses and target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rewrite just for you:

A video that engages and impresses its target audience with a unique story, achievements around the globe, a touching revelation, and hope for a better future.

Now, it's better. Simpler is better. That is now used correctly in the sentence. Maybe /touching revelations/ with an s. But I can't say since I don't know what you are referring to.

Comment: Thank you @Lambie! Could I ask why "worldwide achievements" was changed? Thank you

Comment: I changed it because using it as a countable noun makes it specific to a bunch of specific places. Had it been unaccountable: It was a worldwide achievement (as in worldwide fame or acclaim that are also uncountable)  I would have left it. I find it is stronger and more precise. Worldwide achievement, the achievement COVERS the world. AchievementS around the globe: they are FOUND IN many, many places around the world.

Comment: Ok. And what if would have talked (not sure about a usage of conditional) about e.g. NHL (national hockey league), which united players from the whole world. Would it be a _worldwide achievement_ or an _achievement around the globe_?

Comment: If it HAD talked about  that :), worldwide achievement, because that is like worldwide acclaim. No s. Uncountable noun. Some words go both ways but their meanings change. A worldwide achievement is more abstract.